# Using NOT in Pytholog

Tags: python, prolog, logic

I recently fell in love with Prolog when introduced to Symbolic A.I.
I think that if Python can combine with Prolog, I can be able to make A.I. understand things.

I found the library "Pytholog", and I was very excited to use it... except I can't use not() in Pytholog, unlike in Prolog.

My code is a medical system that can tell someone which drug to take. This is a shortened version:

```
!pip install pytholog
import pytholog as pl

medicine_bash = pl.KnowledgeBase()
medicine_bash([
"relieves(aspirin, headache).",
"relieves(new_med, headache).",
"aggravate(aspirin, asthma).",
"aggravate(aspirin, peptic_ulcer).",
"should_not_take(Person, Drug):- precondition(Person, Precondition), aggravate(Drug, Precondition).",
"should_take(Person, Drug):- suffers_from(Person, Symptom), precondition(Person, Precondition), relieves(Drug, Symptom), not(aggravate(Drug, Precondition)).",
"suffers_from(albert, headache).",
"precondition(albert, peptic_ulcer)."
])

print(medicine_bash.query(pl.Expr("should_take(albert, Drug).")))
```

The above outputs `['No']`. How could I change the not()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use not you need to add `-` before a predicate.

There is also the `neq` keyword, it can be used for inequality `neq(x,y)`  (x is not y)

This is a working version:

```
import pytholog as pl

medicine_bash = pl.KnowledgeBase()
medicine_bash([
"relieves(aspirin, headache)",
"relieves(new_med, headache)",
"-aggravate(new_med, peptic_ulcer)",
"aggravate(aspirin, asthma)",
"aggravate(aspirin, peptic_ulcer)",
"should_take(Person, Drug) :- suffers_from(Person, Symptom), precondition(Person, Pre), relieves(Drug, Symptom), -aggravate(Drug, Pre)",
"suffers_from(albert, headache)",
"precondition(albert, peptic_ulcer)"
])

print(medicine_bash.query(pl.Expr("should_take(albert, Drug)"), show_path=True))
```

The thing that was missing was telling the negative of aggravate for new_med. Also, it is very important (as my debugging verified) to not put the dots on the strings nor the query.

Comment: Hello! Do you mean "- not()"? In my case, it doesn't work :(  and \+ doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi. No, not(), as far as I know, doesn't exist directly in the library. It would need to be simply -aggravate(...)

Comment: -aggravate(...) doesn't work for some reason. It still says "No". I also tried with spaces. Thank anyways ;)

Comment: I took a beating on this one Emma, but I think I got it. Any questions I will be pleased to answer.

Comment: I never heard to phrase "took a beating". Does it mean got a try? I would like to know a way to write \+ or - or not() with pytholog. Thank you.

Comment: @EmmaGao  `took a beating` - It challenged them so it took a long time. Think of boxing match going many rounds instead of just 2 or 3 rounds. They had to do more work to win but it was worth the effort.

Comment: Emma, for the not() statement the code is adjusted. Aggravate is already using the negative statement on should_take and returning which drug the person should take. The \+ was not mentioned in the question so I didn't look for it. Also, I just realized I removed the should_not_take relation you also had, but it should work too.

Comment: Thank you very much! But how does it work? Why when removing the "." makes it run?

Comment: I believe the system interprets the lines one by one and expects a certain format, the dot is probably making the inner system not be able to process the data, just as adding any other character could have an effect. As it is the last character, we would think it shouldn't affect it, but for the system this may be critical depending on how it processes the values.